# Qt: Adjusting QGraphicsView to window size

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to adjust QGraphicsView to size of my window, but my solutions just doesn't work.

[image: short description]

White rectangle is my QGraphicsView. I need to stretch it to cover whole black space and resize it automatically when my app window is resized. Is it possible in Qt?

Here is code used to create QGraphicsView:

```
    TrackWindow::TrackWindow()
{
    tracksTimelineView = new QGraphicsView(this);
    tracksTimelineView->show();
}
```

Comment: Add a layout to your window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael O. already pointed out you need to add a layout to your window, an example of this would be something like this

```
TrackWindow::TrackWindow
{
    tracksTimelineView = new QGraphicsView(this);

    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;

    layout->addWidget(tracksTimelineView);

    this->setLayout(layout);

    tracksTimelineView->show();
}
```

Hope this helped.

**Edit**

If TrackWindow inherits from QMainWindow try this instead

```
TrackWindow::TrackWindow
{
    tracksTimelineView = new QGraphicsView(this);

    tracksTimelineView->show();

    setCentralWidget(tracksTimelineView);
}
```

Comment: just tried your solution, but I got this:
QWidget::setLayout: "Attempting to set QLayout "" on TrackWindow "", which already has a layout". QGraphicsView is still not stretched

Comment: @Lizard_Paszczyk Then don't create layout, but do instead: `this->layout()->addWidget(tracksTimelineView);`

Comment: Does TrackWindow inherit QMainWindow? If so, you could try to call   `setCentralWidget(tracksTimelineView);` instead of creating a layout.

Comment: @CraftyScoundrel This is what I was looking for. It works, Thank you

Comment: @Lizard_Paszczyk glad I could help, added this solution to my answer.